# Executing Anonymous Apex through Real Force Explorer

Tags: apex

I am no longer able to use Real Force Explorer for Anonymous Apex execution. SOQL queries still work fine. Anonymous Apex used to work and I think it stopped at the time when Summer 13 was introduced.
The error message is:

> 'Executing Anonymous Apex...' has encountered a problem. 
>   An internal error occurred during 'Executing Anonymous Apex...' 
>   An internal error occurred during: "Executing Anonymous Apex...". 
>   Failed to send request to https://null.salesforce.com/services/Soap/s/22.0

There is an [issue raised on the bitbucket page](https://bitbucket.org/brsanthu/real-force-explorer/issue/14/execute-anonymouse-does-not-work-after) but there has been no response and I'm not sure whether the original developer is actively involved in the project anymore.

The "null.salesforce" part of the message looks unhealthy, but the connection is defined correctly in Real Force Explorer. It used to work, it continues to work for SOQL. There doesn't appear to be anywhere in preferences to tweak the server that it tries to call.
Is anyone using anonymous apex successfully in RFE still?
Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: I've e-mailed Santhosh (the author of this great tool) few days ago, no response so far :( I'd hate to see it become useless, it used to beat Eclipse one hand tied behind its back. I've given BrainEngine a go too but didn't fell in love.

Comment: I emailed him too but also no answer which leads me to think he's working on other projects now. That would be a shame because this really is an awesome tool, especially for running the same code quickly against different sandboxes, having multiple scripts open at once, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who's come here with the same problem, I had an email from the developer today to announce the release of the new version of Real Force Explorer, 1.0.10. I've just downloaded this and the execute anonymous problem is resolved.
Also for anyone else upgrading, you can copy the "workspace" folder to the new installation and that will bring across your existing connections.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't comment on the issue with RFE I can suggest using an alternative.  Personally I find Workbench to be a great tool.  It's regularly maintained, and has a great tool set include execute apex.  It used to be you had to host it yourself, but now there is a publicly available version at workbench.developerforce.com.

It's helped me a lot when the Dev Console starts timing out inexplicably for longer running apex requests.